# Force Safari to Display only one tab

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension

Is it possible to create an extension for Safari which limits the number of open tabs to one?

I want to create a login page and the user should only be able to use the browser once the login has been submitted.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. You can always listen to "open" event. In that event handler you can check the number of tabs and close all the ones you need or don't need as the case may be.